Springboot throwing connection refused on https port
i have configured server.port=18080 and http.port=18081 in my sprinboot application.
SSL is configured correctly.
My application is running fine.
It is deployed in aws kubernetes. When i access my application endpoint on https://localhost:18080 im getting connection refused inside the pod.
Im able to access the apis using the http port 18081.
when i do netstat, i can see the port 18080 is listening.
I dont see any files created in Tomcat/work directory.
How to debug this?
I restarted the application and its working. What could be the reason for this? there are no core files generated. The memory and CPU usage was fine.
I the thread dump I noticed the 18080-acceptor thread is not present. I only see 18081-Acceptor thread. The other 18080 threads were in waiting on condition state.

Provide code, configuration, how do you run it in kubernetes etc. there is far too little information here to answer it properly.
